# Phaser mouseTap EventListener

Tags: javascript, events, input, phaser-framework

I have got the following update function:

```
function update() {
  game.input.onTap.add((pointer, doubleTap) => {
    console.log(this.input.x)
    console.log(this.input.y)
  })
}
```

this works well but when I look at console after clicking in (20, 52) I see: 20 52 20 52 20 52 20 52 20 52 etc. at least 200 times. I want to enable keyboard input for a specific grid case (sudoku) when you click on a specific case. Is this going to be an issue? Or can I simply write

```
let case = cases[input.y*9+ input.x]  // Here I don't multiply the inputs properly (cases are not 1px wide)
```

and then enable keyboard input?

Comment: I'm confused about what the specific question is. Do you want to know why you're getting the location multiple times, or how to enable keyboard input? If the latter, I'm confused how your second code block ties into this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer what I believe is your question, which is why you are seeing so many items in the console, in your state's `update` you're adding to the game an input add handler for the `onTap` event.

As you can see in [the official On Tap demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/on-tap), you just need to add the handler a single time per state, usually as part of `create` if you want it to be available immediately.

Moving your code to `create()` or otherwise should resolve those console log issues.